# Random list item, but unable to choose the same item twice

Tags: python, random, kivy

Is it possible to run a loop, that chooses a random list item, but is unable to choose the same one twice in a row.
I've tried running it in a thread and with `Clock.schedule_interval`
Im not sure how to keep the loop and GUI running simultaneously.
When the interval goes off, it "resets" the loop. therefore being able to choose the same item again.

```
def toggle(self):
    self.start()
    i = self.root.ids.interval.text #interval
    i = int(i)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.playsound, i)

def playsound(self, *args):
    while True:
        sounds = [1,2,3,4]
        t = random.randrange(len(sounds)-1)
        sounds.append(sounds.pop(t))         
        x = (sounds[-1])     
        if x == 1:
            print("1")
        elif x == 2:
            print("2")
        elif x == 3:
            print("3")
        elif x == 4:
            print("4")
```

Comment: If this is a GUI related problem try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Notwithstanding the unusual code in *playsound()* you should note that you have an infinite loop which will simply consume an entire CPU *ad infinitum*

Comment: Thank you very much, Apu Coder i will in the future and thank you Arthur King.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `sounds` **before** the loop:

```
def playsound():
    sounds = [1,2,3,4]
    while True:
        t = random.randrange(len(sounds)-1)
        ...
```